# id of all selected checkbox is not passing to controller action

Tags: asp.net-core

how to get all ids selected in controller here is my jquery
`
$(document).ready(function () {

```
    $("#checkAll").click(function () {
        $(".checkBox").prop('checked',
            $(this).prop('checked'));
    });

    $("#delete").click(function () {
        var selectedIDs = new Array();
        $('input:checkbox.checkBox').each(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                selectedIDs.push($(this).val());
            }
        });

        var options = {};
        options.url = "/home/AjaxMethod";
        options.type = "POST";
      //  options.data = JSON.stringify(selectedIDs);
        options.data = selectedIDs;
        options.contentType = "application/json";
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.success = function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        };
        options.error = function () {
            alert("Error while deleting the records!");
        };
        $.ajax(options);

    });
});
```

public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string[] selectedIDs)
{
}`

Comment: Can you provide more context into the problem you are facing, what you are expecting, and what you already tried?

Comment: here is my controller action method

Comment: public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string[] a)
        {      }

Answer (score 0):

You need change your js like below:

```
options.data = JSON.stringify(selectedIDs);
```

And be sure add `[FromBody]` before your parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AjaxMethod([FromBody]string[] selectedIDs) {
    return Json(selectedIDs);
}
```

Here is a whole working demo:

View:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll">Check All
<hr />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" value="1">Item 1
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" value="2">Item 2
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" value="3">Item3
<button type="button" id="delete" >Delete</button>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $("#checkAll").click(function () {
            $(".checkBox").prop('checked',
                $(this).prop('checked'));
        });

        $("#delete").click(function () {
            var selectedIDs = new Array();
            $('input:checkbox.checkBox').each(function () {
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    selectedIDs.push($(this).val());
                }
            });
            console.log(selectedIDs);
            var options = {};
            options.url = "/home/AjaxMethod";
            options.type = "POST";
            options.data = JSON.stringify(selectedIDs);
            //options.data = selectedIDs;
            options.contentType = "application/json";
            options.dataType = "json";
            options.success = function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            };
            options.error = function () {
                alert("Error while deleting the records!");
            };
            $.ajax(options);

        });

    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AjaxMethod([FromBody]string[] selectedIDs) {
    return Json(selectedIDs);
}
```

Result:

[image]